# once i add data to a row, a new row dynamically added in datagrid in WPF once i add data to a row How?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i found a problem adding a new row automatically in datagrid in WPF once i fill the data in the row and find same problem deleting the row automatically once i delete all its data ... could any one help me plz ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem exactly?

If your datagrid is bound to a collection of items and is not updating when you add/remove items, try using an ObservableCollection to store your items (rather than a List for example).